# What does the "UV" in "UV completion" stand for?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology

What does the "UV" in "UV completion" stand for?

Also, I'm not sure which tags I should tag this question with.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_completion) answers this in its first sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it displays [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UV stands for Ultraviolet and it is referring to a special kind of divergences in quantum field theory. In NLO loop diagrams, we often encounter divergences (infinite integrals) when we investigate what happens at $k \to \infty$, where $k$ is the internal momentum of a virtual particle in Feynman diagrams. These are precisely the divergences we call "UV divergences". A UV divergence is often due to the fact that we assume the theory is valid up to infinite energies, where in reality this is not true (there are new physics at high energy scales which will change the theory).

A "UV complete" theory is a theory which UV divergences do not occur because this theory *will* be valid at all scales. An example of a UV complete theory is String Theory.

Answer (score 0):

UV = Ultra-Violet = High energy = Small length-scale.

Comment: Well seeing how there are two (named) energy bands *above* UV, I thoroughly disagree with assessment that UV is "high energy." That would be X-rays and $\gamma$-rays.

Comment: @KyleKanos: It is QFT speak for "high energy", though, just like IR is QFT speak for "low energy".